# Placing a videoID in an iframe using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to display YT videos from one of my playlists through AJAX, but I can't really replace the videoID from an `iframe` with the data that I fetched.

I fetched my data like this:

```js
const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY'
const playlistId = "MY_PLAYLIST_ID"
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${apiKey}`

const getData = function () {
 return fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
     return data.items.map(playlist => {
        return {
          videoId: playlist.snippet.resourceId.videoId
        }
      })
    })
}
```

and now I want to test if I can get one of the videoIds onto my `iframe`, so I tried to place it into one of my sections like this:

```js
const playerTag = document.querySelector(".player")

const putVideoOn = function () {
  playerTag.innerHTML = ""
  playerTag.innerHTML = playerTag.innerHTML + `
  <div class="player-video">
   <iframe width="480" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${data.videoId}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
 `
}

// then I ran the function on load

putVideoOn()
```

But I always get an error saying that the variable I injected into my `iframe` link isn't defined.

Comment: It would be really helpful to post the error as well. I did notice that const url is using backticks instead of quotes: `url = \`https:..` instead of `url = 'https:..`

Comment: I don't know, if YouTube will allow what you are planning.

Comment: Here's the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`, then when I used `${playlist.videoId}` I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: playlist is not defined`. When I tried `${videoId}` I got this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: videoId is not defined`. The `url` has backticks because I injected two `consts` in it. When I ran a console.log it gets all the data that I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `data` variable anywhere defined:

```
const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY'
const playlistId = "MY_PLAYLIST_ID"
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${apiKey}`
```

---

You are using `${data.videoId}` in the URL in your `putVideoOn` function but I don't see where the `data` variable is defined.

You are just using it in your `getData` function like so:

```
return data.items.map(playlist => {
    return {
      videoId: playlist.snippet.resourceId.videoId
}
```

but you are not saving anything in the variable `data` because it doesn't exist probably

Comment: Good call...I tried using `${playlist.videoId}` and just `${videoId}` on its own but I still get the same error.

Comment: Hope it worked out for you. Sometimes ( many times ) we miss the most obvious things. Accept my answer when you feel like it :) Good luck.

Comment: Here's the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: playlist is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: videoId is not defined`

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I'll try and have a go at it :)

Comment: No problem. Do let me know in the comments if it still produces the same error. If it doesn't, don't hesitate to start a new thread, I will keep an eye out.